# Finding an Unknown Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out the appropriate method to find a solution.

I have 325 employees from one location. I'm trying to figure out a reasonable percentage of tickets that could have come from those employees if the average ticket count per month is 463 from a total of 10 locations. I have 700 employees in total.

Comment: Please say what you have tried. Just uploading a problem is not the right way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem, explain what the formula means and explain what exactly you are trying to find?

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting equations.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Let me see if I can simplify the question. I have 325 employees from one location. I'm trying to figure out a reasonable percentage of tickets that could have come from those employees if the average ticket count per month is 463 from a total of 10 locations.

Comment: @M.TDavis This is only solvable if you also know the total employee count of all locations combined. Without that it's impossible. The answer is going to be very different if the majority of all employees are concentrated in e.g. this site and all others are nearly empty, or if the other locations have thousands of employees.

Comment: @Peatherfed OK, I wasn't sure if I needed that. The total count for all of the employees would be 700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average number of tickets per employee (across all sites) over the 6-month span was $463 / 700 \approx 0.66$ per month. The unknown site has 325 employees, so, if they obey the average you should have seen roughly $463 / 700 \times 325 \approx 214$ tickets per month from them.

Put another way, that site hosts $325 / 700 \approx 46\%$ of your employees, and so should be responsible for roughly 46% of the average number of tickets, i.e. 46% of 463, which is, again, roughly 214. Of course, this is a rough estimate. The site could have supplied everything from zero to all your tickets, but assuming each site roughly operates at the same efficiency the estimate should be good.